# How to show a preview of a file on a panel in a UiApp using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, blob, thumbnails

I want to display a preview of a(ny) file on a panel in a UiApp using GAS.

I'm using DriveApp, not DocsList.

Using `file.getThumbnail()` or `file.getAs(mimeType)` I can get a Blob of any file.
Documentation at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getThumbnail%28%29 states that (at least) I can get those blobs being converted to 'application/pdf'.

I don't know how to display those blobs (or pdf-files as such) on a panel.
Can anybody tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant display them inside the panel because you would need to iframe it, which isnt possible even with htmlServices.
Use an anchor to open the link on another page. You can link to the original file.

Comment: I already use an anchor and open the file on another page.  So it means it isn't possible to display a preview of a file on a panel (except images). A pitty.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert a spreadsheet with a pdf but i don"t know with any File.

I use this code

```
     var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:'Weekly Status.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
```

You cna test It with this source if he can help you .

https://gist.github.com/ixhd/3660885

Comment: He already said he can convert to pdf and is asking how to display it